# How can I display the user's name after successfully logging in with ReactJS authentication routes?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes

I having trouble showing the user name once it loges in. I have defined the endpoints in my api folder i tested it in postman and work fine, but i want to show the user name once the logs in is successfully executed but it just show it redirects the user to the dashboard route but it acts as it there was no user logged in

this is my log in component

```
function Login({ handleLogin, setUser }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000'
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await api.post('/api/users/login', { email, password });
      console.log(response.data.name);
      // Extract the user's name from the response data
      handleLogin(email, password);
      
      // Handle successful login
      navigate('/dashboard');
    } catch (error) {
      setError('Invalid email or password');
    
    }
  }


  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Log in</button>
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <p className='already-have-account'>Don't have an account? <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link></p>
    </form>
  );
```

this is my dashboard component

```
const Dashboard = ({ user }) => {
  // Check if the user is logged in and has a name
  const isLoggedIn = user !== null && user.name !== null;

  // Render different content based on the user's login status
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <div>
          <h2>Welcome, {user.name}!</h2>
          {/* Render logged-in user content */}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>Please log in to access the dashboard.</h2>
          {/* Render login form or redirect to login page */}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and it gets rendered to my App.js

```
function App() {  

const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
    withCredentials: true // Send cookies along with requests
  });


useEffect(() => {
  const checkLoginStatus = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get('/api/users/checkLoginStatus');
      console.log(response.data);
      setUser(response.data); // Set user state to the logged-in user
    } catch (error) {
      setUser(null); // Set user state back to null
    }
  };

  checkLoginStatus();
}, []);


  const handleLogin = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.post('/api/users/login', { email, password });
      
      setUser(response.data); // Set user state to the logged-in user
       console.log('User logged in successfully:', response.data);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };


return (
 {/* some code */}


 <Route path="/login" element={<Login handleLogin={handleLogin} />} />


 {/* some code */}
)
```

is there anything i should change in my code to show the user's information after logging in

Comment: Just as a side note: use `context` for storing `user` and then access it anywhere down the tree, instead of passing it as a prop

Comment: which one is the parent component of Dashboard? It's not being returned by app and I can't see where user is being passed